# Joomla! core design login dynamic login forms

Tags: php, caching, joomla, joomla2.5

I am facing pretty specific problem right now. I am redoing a forum so there are reply buttons even though the user is not logged in. I am using Kunena. When user who is not logged in clicks the button a Core Design login popup will pop up and after the login the user will be redirected to the reply page.

Now I have this all working except one thing. I am not able to pass the correct redirect address to each of the modules.

Here is the code the render the plugin, I am passing the message id variable (different for each comment and crucial to get to go to correct reply page) :

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = &JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_cdlogin');
echo $this->message->id;
$attribs = array('comment_id'=>$this->message->id);
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module,$attribs);
```

This is inside a foreach loop for each comment on the page. The reply address is:

```
forum/forum-category-alias/2141-topic-alias/reply/2889.html
```

The last number being the ID is crucial for me. I am not able to pass this id to the module. I am but only the first one 2889 gets through. All of the login form modules has this same id, even though it should be higher.

So my question is: why does this module gets the same ID every time it is rendered? Cache somewhere? I have run out of options. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not clear how you iterate through messages so it's difficult to know why $this->message->id would return the same id. Also, it's worth noting that you should only have one login form, and your "Reply" button for guests should invoke it with a javascript call passing in, as a parameter, the url to go back to (base64-encoded, will be added by the javascript to the field return_url of the login module)

Comment: thanks for the comment, it got me to the right track and it is working like a charm now .. thank you!